# Node.js - Cant run project

Tags: javascript, node.js

im trying to run a node.js example project that i downloaded from [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2012/08/nodejs-drawing-game/)

I downloaded node.js and npm and checked both versions using CMD as seen below.
[image: cmd]

At first the version of npm wasnt compatible but i followed a youtube guide and now it seems the versions are compatible. If i didnt mention, im using Windows os.

I then installed the socket package by typing in "npm install socket.io@0.9.10 node-static" in cmd and a bunch of writing happened until it finished.

I then open cmd and do, "cd ... then the folders which contain the project" until its the root folder.

I then type in cmd "node app.js" which is the js file contained in the project.
I get this as a result:
[image: socket]

The tutorial im following then tells me to go to http://localhost:8080 to see a local copy of the demo but when i do, chrome just loads and loads then after a few minutes says it cant be reached. does anyone know what im doing wrong? any help is appriciated

Comment: The deprecation warning is due to the new version of node. It's fine, you may just ignore it.

Comment: you npm is outdated btw. you really should be on 3.x

Comment: can you provide a download link? im on https://nodejs.org/download/release/npm/ and the latest is 1.4.9

Comment: npm should be installed along with Node.JS if you use the installer https://nodejs.org/en/download/ you should also be able to `npm install -g npm@3` to get the latest in the v3 range.

Comment: im kinda new so i just dont know what that means. ive installed node.js

Answer (score 1):

afaict you're not doing anything wrong, Doesn't work for me either. It was written in 2012 so it's quite possible this worked fine with an older version of Node.JS and older versions of some dependencies. To get it working for me locally I made the following changes:

Change the `handler` function in `app.js` to

```
function handler (request, response) {
    fileServer.serve(request, response);
}
```

And instead of installing an old version of socket.io I installed the latest. You may want to delete your `node_modules` directory in the project and then:

```
npm install socket.io node-static
```

Comment: im giving this a try hold on